# How to check digital licenses linked to my Microsoft Account before installing it?

Tags: windows-10, license, microsoft-account, volume-license

My harddrive just crashed and HP is asking me to pay them to get a recovery media in order to re-install Windows on the new hard drive. Now, Windows 10 uses digital licenses tied to out Microsoft Account. So, I guess I should be able to grab a iso of the same edition of Windows online, install it, and then activate it by signing in to my MS Account.
Only thing I can't seem to figure out is how do I check if I have a digital license linked to my account. https://account.microsoft.com/devices does show my connected devices but there isn't any option to check my license. Also,found a answer elsewhere stating that this page only shows the devices linked, not the one which have license.
What I want to know is , How do I check whether the digital license is there in my MS Account or not ?

Comment: Just download the ISO from Microsoft and install Windows 10, your OEM license, will automatically activate.  Checking if you have a digital license is a waste of time (you do have one), I have written at least 10 answers, to various questions that answer your question

Comment: no disrespect, but how can you be so sure ? @Ramhound

Comment: I have already documented how I know the answer to this question in other answers, if you don’t believe me, that is fine.

Comment: *sigh* I would also like to know the answer. I somehow managed to have two MS accounts, I'd like to know which one has my current windows licence so I can close the other one.

Comment: @Ramhound you are forgetting that if you install from a usb stick, if you don't know which version you previously had installed, you can end up installing the wrong one, and it won't activate after installation.

Comment: @JohnLord - I didn’t forget. I just figure that’s irrelevant to mention. Definitely not worth replying to a 4 year old comment.

Comment: It was relevant because i've done it myself and had to re-install again.  Plus this question is closed so i can't exactly add my own answer.  You need to keep in mind that this question may be four years old but it's still relevant to people because windows 10 isn't dead yet.  I just re-installed it on a laptop yesterday.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question since the main question in the title "How to check digital licenses linked to my Microsoft Account?" is not covered in the question that supposedly duplicates this one. Not sure why they are flagged as duplicates. I would like to see an answer to that exact question.

Comment: I was downvoted very frequently back then so I didn't really pursue this much, but I've also flagged this question reporting it's not the same as the question it's been linked to. Hopefully they re-open it @SimonE.

Comment: The remaining question is about licensing (off topic) and the Microsoft account (also off topic). Microsoft does not only use Windows licenses just associated with your digital account. On modern hardware the license is written in the BIOS. You probably have Home edition, unless you purchased some other version, but that is unlikely on a regular computer.

Answer (score -3):

Download the same edition you had on your old computer by using the Microsoft's Media Creation Tool. If your product key is stored in the computer's motherboard it should automatically insert it during the installation process. If not, when asked you choose "I don't have a product key".

On the part when when Windows installation assistant asks you to create or insert your existing Microsoft account you enter your Microsoft account and when the install is finished your copy of Windows should be activated.

Comment: My question was how do I check if my account has a digital license linked to it. This does not answer my question.

Comment: It answers your question only not in "direct" way cause if your product actually gets activated after entering your microsoft account you will know: Yes you have a digital licence, if not you don't.

Comment: If you go to settings -> Updates & Security -> Activation it will also tell you if your Windows is activated by a digital license.

Comment: Read the question, hard drive CRASHED

Comment: I know, but after you reinstall Windows in the new harddrive and sign in with your microsoft account

Comment: Only if it was linked with the account before the hard drive crashed, which is why @AbhishekRanjan wants to check _before_ installation.